# White screen of death errors

Tags: 7, wsod

I have come across an error that I have been having difficulty fixing.
I am suspicious the problem is the "Primary script unknown" error, but I am lost. There is an reoccurring Fatal Error, but it is a core file that has never been modified..

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

See below for an example of the nginx error log.

> 2016/01/09 08:08:17 [error] 1082#0: *315 FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script  unknown" while reading response header from upstream, client: 188.68.224.62, server: , request: "GET http://dhg.pisz.pl/httptest.php HTTP/1.1", upstream:  "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock:", host: "dhg.pisz.pl"

Answer (score 0):

The error you've shown is from someone running a hacking script.

The nginx documentation offers many solutions to avoid running bad php scripts in their [Pitfalls and Common Mistakes FAQ](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/#passing-uncontrolled-requests-to-php), but the one I like is the try_files directive to only run scripts that exist on your server otherwise return a 404 Not Found status code.

```
location ~* \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_pass backend;
    # [...]
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try this when I have a little more time and let you know how it works. And if you don't mind, if I cannot work my way through the guide, I may have a question or two.I really appreciate the help and guidance.

Comment: Hello, I have added try_files to the nginx/sites-available but I the website still only shows the NGINX error page for every single page. There seems to be something that is creating a disconnect between my site and the server. Is it possible I am just not employing the try_files correctly? Thank you

Comment: Hello Bestinc, I have no information to answer your question.
What errors do you see in the nginx/php logs? Is the PHP server running? Do you have a missing semicolon?

Comment: PHP is running. I can get to my phpinfo() variable. The errors that keep showing up are Primary Script Unknown errors. I have since found out that Every page is sent to a 503 error page except the login page that attempts and fails to redirect to some other page. It seems like there is a script running on there for sure, redirecting the pages/obscuring the page loads.